# How to exclude a namespace from a Sandcastle documentation using the Visual Studio plug-in?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, documentation, documentation-generation, sandcastle

The question is as stated above, I've tried using `<exclude />` before the name of the namespace, but it didn't work. Also, I've tried changing `MRefBuilder.config` file by adding

```
<apiFilter expose="true">
  <namespace name="WpiApi.Areas" expose="false"></namespace>    
</apiFilter>
```

but it didn't work either. I put it inside `<attributeFilter/>`. No luck here. I've run out of options, can you give me a working solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oh man, it's in the `Components` tab...

Comment: You might word it as an answer, rather than a verbal expression of facepalming.

Answer (score 2):

This setting is (as of v2017.5.15.0) in the *Summaries* tab.

Click the *Edit Namespace Summaries*. The dialog displays all the namespaces in the documentation sources in a checkbox list. Just uncheck the ones you want to exclude (and for the others, you can enter summary text to appear on their pages).